# How to get to the "final predecessor" with a CONNECT BY query?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, connect-by

I have a table, `SELECT * FROM data`

```
id   pred   name        visual link, for your convenience
--------------------
 1   null   One              
20   null   Two         <--+
21     20   Three         -^
30   null   Four              <--+      
31     30   Five                -^  <--+ 
32     31   Six                       -^
```

In which the rows are connected via the `pred` column to the `id` column. They form only chains and not a tree -- each node has only one or zero successors (if that's important).

**I want to add a column `init` to the query where the very first element in the chain is shown**, i.e.

```
id   pred   name    init initname
---------------------------------
 1   null   One        1 One
20   null   Two       20 Two
21     20   Three     20 Two
30   null   Four      30 Four
31     30   Five      30 Four
32     31   Six       30 Four
```

- It would be ok if rows with `pred=null` also show `null` for `init`.
- The `initname` column is completely optional and I show it here only for demonstration, I only need the `id`.

From what I gathered about **the `connect by` clause** I managed a somewhat reverse result, where for each "root" its "child" nodes are listed. I don't know how to "turn the query around".

```
SELECT id, pred, CONNECT_BY_ROOT id init, LEVEL, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF "IsLeaf"
FROM data
CONNECT BY PRIOR pred=id
ORDER BY id, level;
```

Gives the result

```
id  pred   init lvl isLeaf
--------------------------
1   null    1   1   1
20  null    20  1   1
20  null    21  2   1
21  20      21  1   0
30  null    30  1   1
30  null    31  2   1
30  null    32  3   1
31  30      31  1   0
31  30      32  2   0
32  31      32  1   0
```

which somehow represents the the whole "tree", obviously. **But alas, "the wrong way around".** I'd need for example

```
id  pred  init lvl isLeaf
21   20    0     ?   ?
```

instead of

```
id  pred init lvl isLeaf
21   20   21   1     0
```

---

If you need data, here is the example data:

```
create table data ( id number primary key, pred number, name varchar2(100) );
insert into data(id,pred,name) values(     1 ,  null  , 'One');
insert into data(id,pred,name) values(    20,   null  , 'Two');
insert into data(id,pred,name) values(21,     20  , 'Three');
insert into data(id,pred,name) values(30,   null ,  'Four');
insert into data(id,pred,name) values(31,     30 ,  'Five');
insert into data(id,pred,name) values(32,     31 ,  'Six');
```

Comment: Use `CONNECT BY PRIOR id = pred START WITH pred IS NULL`.

Comment: @Rachcha no that doesn't do the trick. (see comment on Rustys answer

Comment: look closely at the `CONNECT BY` line. That's the root of your problem and my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SQL>  select id
  2        , pred
  3        , name
  4        , connect_by_root id             init
  5        , connect_by_root name           initname
  6        , sys_connect_by_path(id,' -> ') scbp
  7     from data
  8  connect by prior id = pred
  9    start with pred is null
 10  /

        ID       PRED NAME             INIT INITNAME   SCBP
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------
         1            One                 1 One         -> 1
        20            Two                20 Two         -> 20
        21         20 Three              20 Two         -> 20 -> 21
        30            Four               30 Four        -> 30
        31         30 Five               30 Four        -> 30 -> 31
        32         31 Six                30 Four        -> 30 -> 31 -> 32

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: You mean, my mistake has been to use `connect by prior pred=id` instead of `connect by prior id=pred`? Whow.

Comment: Yes. Others have tried to tell you, but seeing is believing :-)

Comment: Yes, I did not notice the difference. I did not expect the order is important, so I did not "look close enough". Now that I "have seen" it is of course obvious that the order in fact *is* important.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use following expression to get name of the root element:

```
substr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, '/'), instr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, '/'), '/', -1)+1)
```

Replace delimiter '/' if needed.

```
SELECT id, pred, CONNECT_BY_ROOT id init, LEVEL, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF "IsLeaf", 
       substr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, '/'), instr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, '/'), '/', -1)+1)
FROM data
CONNECT BY PRIOR pred=id
--    START WITH pred is NULL --???
ORDER BY id, level;
```

You probably need to add START WITH clause as well

Comment: No, that gives me `1,null,1`, `20,null,20`, `30,null,30`, plus the level and isleaf info. Still, I think it is "the wrong way around". For example, I need the result for all the rows and not for only the `pred is null` rows.

Comment: I mean you anyway have to have this clause otherwise you will see full tree and all subtrees (duplications), especially if you insert more data.

Comment: An interesting approach. "start with" is still wrong. Your result contains everything I need and the unique rows I need are those with "max level". I could do that with a subclause and `group by`. I wonder if there is another `substr`-less solution, though...

Comment: I don't think that you can refer on root element in hierarchal SQL somehow else because you don't know how deep your current row is in your tree (chain).

Comment: My most recent research got me to `select id, pred, name, init, (select name from data where id=init) initname
from (
    SELECT d1.*, (select d2.id init from data d2 where CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF=1 start with d2.id=d1.id CONNECT BY PRIOR pred=id) init
    FROM data d1
    ORDER BY id ) xdata;`, which looks quite good. I'd like to get rid of the proliferating subqueries, though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the result with a nested query.

```
select id, pred, name, init, (select name from data where id=init) initname
from (
    SELECT d1.*
      , (select d2.id init
           from data d2
         where CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF=1 start with d2.id=d1.id CONNECT BY PRIOR pred=id) init
    FROM data d1
    ORDER BY id ) xdata
;
```

As you can see, to get the `initname` I need an additional subquery this way. This is not perfect, but good enough -- the query is on the PK.

```
id pred Name    init initname
------------------------------
1       One     1    One
20      Two     20   Two
21  20  Three   20   Two
30      Four    30   Four
31  30  Five    30   Four
32  31  Six     30   Four
```